# How do you display your php source code with highlight or view source?

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting

How do you display your php source code with highlight or view source or is there more alternatives to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP has two native functions that might be of interest: [`highlight_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php) and [`highlight_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php). If neither of those are ideal, you could also use [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) to achieve this result. This is the solution many use, including StackOverflow itself.

Alternatives:

- [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter)
- [SHJS](http://shjs.sourceforge.net/)
- [jQuery Chili](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-chili-js/)
- [Lighter for MooTools](http://pradador.com/code/lighterjs/)
- [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the php [`highlight_file`](http://us.php.net/highlight_file) function to echo the source of a file with syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

On many servers if you give it a .phps file extension the source code will be displayed and highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

[GeSHi - Generic Syntax Highlighter](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) is another opensource javascript library.

Answer (score 0):

I do my editing in gvim which can be configured to do syntax sensitive code highlighting (amongst other things).

PHP has a builtin function which converts a string to coloured HTML

http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php

so...

```
<?php

print highlight_string(file_get_contents(__FILE__));

?>
```

demonstrates this.

You might also wnat to have a lokk at GeSHi

http://qbnz.com/highlighter/

HTH

C.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to load my scripts form foreign hosts each time - especially not from search engines like PRISM. This is not that secure and load-time-killing. If you have experience with RegExp it's quick done.

Here is a snippet I used for a short PHP tutorial. You need to complete it with some CSS, commands in the last RegExp and an onload='init()' in the body-tag.

```
function init() { 
   var codes= document.getElementsByTagName('code')
      ,str= ''
      ,len= codes.length
      ,c= 0
      ;
   for(c; c < len; c++){ 
      str = codes[c].textContent;   
      str=str.replace(/(\bnull\b|\b[0-9]+\b|\btrue\b|\bfalse\b|"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"|'(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*')/g,"<span class=\"text\">$1</span>");
      str=str.replace(/(\(|\)|\[|\]|\{|\})/g,"<span class='bracket'>$&</span>");
      str=str.replace(/\$[a-z]\w*/gi,"<span class='variable'>$&</span>");
      str=str.replace(/( \! | \!\= | \!== | = | == | === | > | >= | < | <= | and | or )/g,"<span class='operator'>$&</span>");
      str=str.replace(/\b(for|function|return|unset|count|global|if|else|else if|intval|int|array)\b/g,"<span class='command'>$1</span>");
      codes[c].innerHTML=str;
   }
}
```