# How can I get php source code to display neatly on my website?

Tags: php, formatting

is there some Javascript/CSS snippet or perhaps another solution to parse PHP source code intended as content on a web page so that it has highlighted elements for commands, variables, brackets etc?

Comment: Has been asked and answered just yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155588/how-do-you-display-your-php-source-code-with-highlight-or-view-source

Comment: I wouldn't close for the sake that the other question had incomplete answers or ones pertaining to entire PHP files (as the correct solution) and not snippets.

Comment: @cballou `highlight_string` lets you highlight just a snippet and I would bet at least one of the other eight solutions can highlight snippets too.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a built in feature that allows you to rename your PHP files to ".phps", this stands for "PHP Source" or something. This will display nicely formatted PHP code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).

Answer (score 0):

[SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter)

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if i've understood well your question bu if you want a syntax highlight on a php function use the [highlight_file function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php)

Answer (score 0):

[Github's GISTs](http://gist.github.com/) can be made public and included directly in your pages.  I really wish they'd add tabbing to the editor window, however.